# passwords on upgraded firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, passwords

I was running firefox 22.0 on Fedora 17 and installed firefox 33.1.1.  I saved the old firefox so I can switch between.  Both show that they are using the same profile.  Using 22.0 I can see my passwords but not on 33.1.1.  Since the profile is the same, what do I have to do to see my old passwords?

Comment: Have you tried to export them, then import them, after doing a backup of your profile directory of course.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue. You can import the profile informations in to the new firefox instance.

**Steps to copy profile info from old instance:**

- click menu button --> help  --> select Troubleshooting
  Information(This will open trouble shooting tab)
- Under Application Basics section click the show folder which will
  open a window that is having your profile related file
- Exit the firefox
- copy the profile file from older firefox and paste it inside new
  firefox profile folder.

**Note :** During copy and paste process firefox instance has to be in closed status.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question - **they are using the same profile**